# Do C++ references always point to the same object? What about this specific case?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am a SWE learning C++ and have a question about references - sorry if it is too simple. References are always explained to be "immutable" in that they "always point to the same object". Otherwise, you would not be able to assign anything new to it. For example:

```
int x;         // an int
int &refX = x; // reference to x
refX = 5;      // here, a new `int` object gets instantiated and overwrites x
```

so, refX no longer points to the same object! I guess a more correct definition would be that it always points to the same address location. Is this correct? In this case, it behaves pretty much like a const*, except you don't have to use the * operator. Am I missing something?

Thank you!

Comment: It still points to the same place in the memory it did. The value at that place got overwritten, the reference didn't change.

Comment: In this case, `x = 5` and `refX = 5`

Comment: I think I narrowly understand the question that you are trying to ask but don't feel as if you're explaining it too correctly.You cannot change the address of a variable, at any point under any cost, you can change what it points to though, whenever you'd want to. Maybe clarify just a bit if you are talking about the address being pointed to or the address of the variable itself?

Comment: Yes! That is exactly right. Sorry it was not clearer, English is not my first language. So its not that it always points to the same object, but to the same memory location?

Comment: "would not be able to assign anything new to it" means you cant change its pointing address and `refX=5` just plays with its value but address remains same.

Comment: References are basically used so that you can have two ways of referring to the same place in memory. So yeah, it's like you had another variable of the same type, at the same place in memory. One of them gets updated, the value of other's naturally also changes.

Comment: I guess your problem is the usage of the word object. What do you mean by 'the same object'? Even if you assign 5 via reference to the int, it's still the same int, only with different value.

Comment: @ManuelMenzella You should look up a good article on the differences between a constant pointer to non-constant data and a non-constant pointer to constant data. I think it'll help you understand some of the issues you are having.

Comment: Well if you initialized refX as a reference variable then when you do that you must give it something that it alludes to. After that point, unless you are dealing with an initialized pointer, you cannot change that address, least to my known points. You have basically just made refX a handle to the same slice of data in memory that x was stored in, it is, if I get what you are saying, just &x == &refX == whatever_address_x_points_to. You've made a copy of x that is all, you cannot make refX point to another location. So yes what you stated in the comment is more or less correct.

Answer (score 3):

I use to think about a reference as an alias for another object. If you apply this to people, the alias is a nickname.

For example, if you have:

```
Person   Robert;
Person&  Bob = Robert;
```

you only have one person, but you sometimes call him Robert and sometimes call him Bob. But he is still the same person.

Trying to involve Bob's address into this just makes it harder. I find it easier to just consider references at the abstract level - two names for the same thing.